# Spring Kafka: Read from two different topics in order

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Is it possible with Spring Kafka to read from two different topics in different consumers in a guaranteed order? For example, topic A stores information that is pertinent to determine how to handle the data that is stored in topic B. Topic A is read into memory and referenced, but needs to be completely populated before reading data in from topic B. Below is an example of what my current setup looks like...

```
@Service
public class TopicA {
  @KafkaListener(topics = "topicA")
  public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record) {
    // ... some code here to populate an in-memory data structure
  }
}
```

```
@Service
public class TopicB {
  @KafkaListener(topics = "topicB")
  public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record) {
    // ... some code here that depends on topic A having populated the in-memory data structure
  }
}
```

So far I've been leaning towards creating a Spring startup process (using @PostConstruct) that initializes the data structure by reading from topic A first, but have not been able to get that working. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you should make topic A should be a KTable and you want to join data across that and B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@KafkaListener(id = "bConsumer" topics = "topicB", autoStartup = "false")
```

Then autowire the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean and `registry.getListenerContainer("bConsumer").start();` when you are ready.

Comment: So the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` would be autowired into the `topicA` class and would start up the topic B consumer only after it's populated the data structure fully? Do you have any suggestions for how I can tell that a Kafka topic has been read from completely? I'm always reading from the beginning using `consumerSeekCallback.seekToBeginning()`.

Comment: You can set the container's `idleEventInterval` and consume a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` when that interval has passed without receiving any new records. You can consume the event by implementing `ApplicationListener` or adding an `@EventListener` method. See [Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#events) and [Consuming Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#event-consumption).